# Export/Import Gitlab Repo with multiple projects

Tags: gitlab

I'm looking for a good way to export 100+ projects from one Gitlab repo on one server and import them into another existing Gitlab repo on another server. I need to be able to export/import:

- projects
- gitlab code (master and all branches and all prior commits)
- tickets (and comments and previous status')
- gitlab variables/secrets

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are the same version of gitlab you can backup and restore using bundled rake tasks.
The details can be found here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md

The backup will produce a tarball you can move from the initial server to the target and then restore.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28402358)